Checking whether page ran as PWA not working on Chrome on Android
I'm using
window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches

to try to check whether my page is running as a PWA. This works on Desktop, but on Android, this returns false despite the page running in the app.
My manifest has display: 'fullscreen' so I also tried that with no success. Really I tried any possible value of display-mode and they are all false in that scenario.
Any idea why?
